# Fancybox 2 - Include a new Div into Image?

Tags: fancybox

How can I insert a new div (not in .js) into fancybox (when fancybox - image is open)? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also try to make a div css to fit that description :)) still with no avail. I suck at css styling, will get back on this one when i figured it out. my theory is that it should be a div within a div within the div if you get what i mean :))

!!!!!!!!
UPDATE I tried messing around the css and this is what i got (I'm using ***1.3.4v*** for simplicity's sake in my part) and for reference, these images and codes I used are found in the 1.3.4 demo packege from fancybox.net

If I didn't explain my code well, it just means I'm still working on it so I just hope you get why it is vague, but the point is it's doable and you only need to work out the css file. I hope someone has a nicer looking code

Output:
[image: MySampleTry]

1.**I all of these from jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css**
just change these 1 2 3 and mess around with example7 there in the demo

```
 #fancybox-outer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #fff;
padding-right:50%;  /*this part extends the right side of the photo so it would look like thet're on the same page*/
  }
```

2.This re-positions the original title to the upper right part of the image

```
.fancybox-title-inside {
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-align: left;
color: #333;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:65%;
border:1px solid black;/*for you to see how large the div is*/
height:100%;
}
```

3.My new RED div where I will be

```
div.fancycontent{ /*saviour do word wrap here*/
border:1px solid black;
padding:2px;
color: #333;
background: #FF0000;
width:50%;
height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using fancybox in one of my projects but had to revert back to implementing my own popup's using the DIV elements. Its pretty easy to create your own popups instead of using fancybox or facebox if you know a bit of JQuery try to have a look at these links. You can customize your div tags to contain what ever you need.

[output](http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/popupjquery/)
[source](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

In your fancybox JS, set the type to iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.callout').fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        width:  '640px',
        height: '480px',
    });
});
```

Then you can open up anything you want in the fancybox by simply applying the class to your link:

```
<a class="callout" href="{path}">{link}</a>
```

If you have issues with the iframe display, you might try adding a secondary class to tell fancybox what type of content you are linking to (this is a new convention introduced in the latest version, so I don't know if I'd recommend using it by default):

```
<a class="callout callout.iframe" href="{path}">{link}</a>
```

Hope that helps!

ty

Answer (score 0):

It just happened that I created this fancybox "a la" facebook demo that looks pretty much like what you want:

http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html